# Core Data: How do I store a custom object as a transformable attribute?

Tags: swift, class, core-data, transformable

Currently I have a class called Place defined as follows:

```
class Place  {

    let name: String
    let address: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let type: String
    var photoReference: String?
    var photo: UIImage?

    /* functions etc */
}
```

In my data model, I have an entity, called FoundPlaces. It has one attribute, `place`, of type "transformable."

I am going insane trying to find the Swift solution to storing this object. Is the data model to begin with wrong?

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The object stored in the transformable attribute needs to implement the `NSCoding` protocol (`init(coder:)` and `encodeWithCoder:`).

The simplest way is to have the `Place` class inherit from `NSObject` and implement the methods above.